# Group by on Postgresql Date Time

Tags: database, postgresql, group-by

Hy. There are employee records in my postgresql database something like

```
 CODE     DATE       COUNT 
"3443"   "2009-04-02"  3
"3444"   "2009-04-06"  1
"3443"   "2009-04-06"  1
"3443"   "2009-04-07"  7
```

I want to use a query "SELECT ALL CODES AND COUNT THEM THAT OCCURRED IN THE MONTH"

RESULT:

```
 CODE     DATE     COUNT 
"3443"   "2009-04"  3
"3441"   "2009-04"  13
"3442"   "2009-04"  11
"3445"   "2009-04"  72
```

I did use a query i.e.

```
SELECT CODE,date_part('month',DATE),count(CODE)
FROM employee
where 
group by CODE,DATE
```

The above query runs fine but the months listed in the records are in form of numbers and its hard to find that a month belongs to which year. In short I want to get the result just like mention above in the RESULT section. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CODE, to_char(DATE, 'YYYY-MM'), count(CODE)
FROM employee
where 
group by CODE, to_char(DATE, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Answer (score 13):

Depending on whether you want the result as text or a date, you can also write it like this:

```
SELECT CODE, date_trunc('month', DATE), COUNT(*)
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY CODE, date_trunc('month', DATE);
```

Which in your example would return this, with DATE still a timestamp, which can be useful if you are going to do further calculations on it since no conversions are necessary:

```
 CODE     DATE     COUNT 
"3443"   "2009-04-01"  3
"3441"   "2009-04-01"  13
"3442"   "2009-04-01"  11
"3445"   "2009-04-01"  72
```

`date_trunc()` also accepts other values, for instance `quarter`, `year` etc.
See the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) for all values

Comment: It is possible to specify `date_trunc('month', DATE) AS mydate` and then use `mydate` in the rest of the query (e.g. in `GROUP BY`).

Answer (score 1):

Try any of

```
SELECT CODE,count(CODE),
    DATE as date_normal, 
    date_part('year', DATE) as year, 
    date_part('month', DATE) as month, 
    to_timestamp(
        date_part('year', DATE)::text 
        || date_part('month', DATE)::text, 'YYYYMM')
        as date_month
FROM employee
where 
group by CODE,DATE;
```